# How can I change the colour of the text of a grid view item,at state pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

I am having a grid view,every item as a text view.initially the text color is white and the background color is transparent,when it is pressed the item background color will get change to white,in this case the text color and the item color is white.So on pressed the whole layout will get white.

I want to set the text colour of the grid item on pressed programmatically ,I know I can change the colour of the text using selector.

but I want to set the text colour programmatically,according to background color.

```
gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv_list_item_lang=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item_lang);



            Constants.survey_language = ""
                    + languagesNameList.get(position);
            Log.d("survey_language", "" + languagesNameList.get(position));
            try {
                if (Constants.questions_arr_list.size() == 0) {
                    getCurrentSurveyQuestions();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("exception", "" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }

            // Intent intent=new
            // Intent(SurveyYesNoActivity.this,TwoQuestionsActivity.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
            // finish();
            gridView2.setEnabled(false);
});
```

need help...thanks in advance!

Comment: Asif have a look on the code i have shared.

Answer (score 3):

Make a `color` folder in the `res`

Make a selector in the same folder with any name say text_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/app_mail_blue"/>
    <item android:color="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

and set the `textColor` of TextView as             `android:textColor="@color/text_pressed"`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text View"
        android:textColor="@color/text_pressed" />
```

Comment: i know i can use selector,is there any way that i can change the text color only at the state pressed proramatically!??...worried!!(without using selector file)

Comment: is there any way i can make the whole selector file programatically?

Comment: well obviously there are ways, but i will prefer you to use in xml.

Comment: can  you tell me how,it will be very helpful for me now.